# Good books about number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

As a physic undergraduate with some knowledge of calculus (Lebesgue integral, stochastic analysis, complex analysis) I'm interested in learning about number theory.

Anyone who has a good tip for me, with which book to start?

Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind being a little bit more specific about your knowledge of calculus? I have (almost) no idea what "analysis I to IV" covers.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I know about differential calculus, i know the lebesgue integral, a little of measurement theory. I had a course in stochastic and complex analysis as well.

Comment: You should edit this into the question, so that everyone can see it more easily.

Comment: Bordes "Arithmetic Tales" or Laroche "escapade arithmetique"

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a sensible undergrad text.  I like Ken Rosen's *Elementary Number Theory* because it has lots of exercises and introduces almost every topic in the field.

After that, there are two books:  Ireland and Rosen's (different Rosen) *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*, which will introduce the algebraic side of number theory, and Apostol's *, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, for the analytic side.

Then maybe Silverman/Tate *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*.